# how to disable Yoast SEO schema from homepage only?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I know it can be disabled everywhere with

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_json_ld_output', '__return_false' );
```

But i want to keep the breadcrumbs so if i could do that only `if (is_home())` that would be perfect. I just don't know where to hook it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
function filter_wpseo_json_ld_output( $bool, $context ) { 
    if(is_home()){ return false; }
    return $bool; 
}; 
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'wpseo_json_ld_output', 'filter_wpseo_json_ld_output', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works! I see you replaced __return_false with your own function but how did you know about those 2 arguments?

Comment: Check here http://hookr.io/plugins/yoast-seo/4.7.1/filters/wpseo_json_ld_output/

Comment: Cool thanks!!!!

Comment: You can also use is_front_page() if the homepage is a static one.